# Map definitions to columns efficiently in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a raw table (hundreds of millions of rows, but I would only be processing 1 day a time which is under a million) that has columns which capture the number of seconds an event lasted.

```
dimensions, status_1_time, status_2_time, ..., status_10_time
```

The problem is that the definitions of the statuses are not uniform. Attempts to standardize them have not been successful historically.

Is there an efficient way to use a lookup table to join back to the raw table where people would map the status code to a standard definition? So each row would indicate the corresponding status code which represents that standard status name.

```
dimensions, lunch_time, paid_training_time, ..., break_time
                 2,             0,          ...,     10
                 1,             4,          ...,      2
```

My naive approach for testing was to have a CASE statement (10 codes and 10 different status columns makes the query quite lengthy and bit repetitive).

```
(CASE 
  WHEN lunch_time = 1 THEN status_1_time
  WHEN lunch_time = 2 THEN status_2_time
  ...
  WHEN lunch_time = 10 THEN status_time
END) AS lunch_break_time
```

Anyone have any suggestions for a better approach or a more efficient way to do this? In the end, I want to send a report with columns like "Lunch Break Time", "Paid Training Time", "Break Time", and leave out the raw status_time columns.

Comment: You could use an array: `(array[status_1_time, status_2_time, ...])[lunch_time]`?

Comment: Your method is fine, if cumbersome.  The real solution would be to fix the data structure, but that doesn't seem likely in this case.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I have not looked into arrays at all for SQL so I will definitely take a look at some examples. And yes, the correct solution is standardization, but it just won't happen